# Using radio buttons in PHP registration form to agree or disagree to Terms and Conditions

Tags: php, mysql, forms, authentication, dreamweaver

I've searched for this answer and cannot find it. If you can point me to it, I will look at it. I'm working in Dreamweaver and fairly new to PHP and MySQL etc. My issue is: I have a simple PHP registration form for visitors to fill out (email, username, password and radio buttons for "Agree to terms" or "Disagree") so they can log into my site and view content. All works fine except I want visitors to click on "Agree to terms", otherwise it will not let them in. As of now, I can still create new accounts (in my testing) regardless of leaving the selection on disagree. I have seen answers using JavaScript but is there an answer in PHP?  Here is that portion of the form if it helps. Thank you in advance.

```html
<label>
       <input   name="AgreeDisagree" type="radio" required id="AgreeDisagree_0" form="register">
       I agree to the <a href="agreement.html">Terms and Conditions</a></label>
     <br>
     <br>
     <label>
       <input name="AgreeDisagree" type="radio" id="AgreeDisagree" value="radio" checked="checked">
       I disagree.</label>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the value in each radio field to "agree" and "disagree" respectively(not "radio"), and then have your backend code make sure `$_POST['AgreeDisagree'] == "agree"`

Comment: That or use javascript to validate agree has been chosen before enabled the submit button.

Comment: Your first answer is the better one, as Newsong80 has mentioned, the goal was a pure php solution and not using javascript - but i agree, that if the user would be a little more firm, using javascript is the better solution in general, since it gives a better user experience

Comment: I can copy/paste javascript if you tell me what and where. I changed the "not 'radio' part. There is no mention of the radio buttons in the PHP that I see (probably why they don't work, ha).

Comment: What PHP are you looking at?  We have minimal code presented to us.

Comment: Here is where you can find the source code. http://www.thelivingoracles.org/register.php

Comment: Rendered HTML output isn't the code we'd need to see.  We'd need to see the backend PHP that is processing all the user input after submit is clicked.